I have a problem with the TensorFlow packages
Could someone help me with the following problem. I am trying to use a python program in Jupyter using visual studio. The program is called Segment_every_grain.ipynb
I am running the following command lines:
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
%matplotlib qt

and I have the following problems:
Import "tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy" could not be resolved
Import "tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image" could not be resolved
'%matplotlib' widget works best inside of VS Code

Attached is an image with the code, I installed using pip3 install tensorflow. I don't know how to solve it.
thank you very much for your reply
greetings

I tried to run it this way:
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras import preprocessing 
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import adam_v2

Although I do not see the problems, but I cannot find Adam, nor preprocessing.image.

These are IDE messages, not python messages, you code probably runs, did you try it?

Please read How do I ask a good question?, especially the section 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem', and then revise your title.
